# Edit html in Magento child

Tags: magento, magento2, bitnami

im new to Magento and want to know, how to change html files in a child.

I installed a theme (Porto) and created a child. As I understand, I have to copy the html files I want to change into the child folder and edit them.
But from where do I take the html files and in which folder I have to put them into the child?

Is there anything to do that magento takes the html file in the child or is this  activated without further changes?

Bonus question: CSS changes best practice - in Magentos custom css field or in childs css file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I edit html pages in Magentos Content -> Pages, does it affect the original theme or the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not just create but to make this child theme active too. After that all you need to do is to copy needed file under the same path as in parent theme.

For example if you need to change header.phtml you have to create folders in you child theme like this:

> Magento_Theme->templates->html

and them copy header.phtml from parent in this folder.

Then you can change anything you need in this file.

As for CSS - I'm always changing styles in child theme, because if main theme files are going to be updated - you will loose all your changes.